# ¿Como quitar las columnas de un datatable?

Tags: javascript, datatables

¡Hola!, necesito eliminar las columnas que no deseo que esten ahi , estoy usando datatables , y me produce ese problema al imprimir, al exportar a excel y a pdf , Imágen de referencia:

[image: Pdf]

Por ejemplo , se me corta en pdf ya que es una tabla larga, quisiera mostrar solamente las columnas que deseo , y en torno a excel , me agrega columnas como lo es "eliminar,"visualizar" y "editar " , quisiera eliminarlo tambien , al igual que se produce al imprimir !

(editado)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#example').DataTable({        
        language: {
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "Primero",
                    "sLast":"Último",
                    "sNext":"Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                 },
                 "sProcessing":"Procesando...",
            },
        //para usar los botones   
        responsive: "true",
        dom: 'Bfrtilp',       
        buttons:[ 
            {
                extend:    'excelHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> ',
                titleAttr: 'Exportar a Excel',
                className: 'btn btn-success'
            },
            {
                extend:    'pdfHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> ',
                titleAttr: 'Exportar a PDF',
                className: 'btn btn-danger'
            },
            {
                extend:    'print',
                text:      '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> ',
                titleAttr: 'Imprimir',
                className: 'btn btn-info'
            },
        ],"columnDefs":[
            {
                "targets": [0,1,2,3],
                "visible": false
             }
        ]        
    });     
});
```

(Editado 2)

Bueno, encontre una solución optativa que me sirvio , lo producire aqui , en caso de que a alguien le ayude! ,Hasta pronto ! :

```js
  $('#example').DataTable({        
        language: {
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "Primero",
                    "sLast":"Último",
                    "sNext":"Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                 },
                 "sProcessing":"Procesando...",
            },
        //para usar los botones   
        responsive: "true",
        dom: 'Bfrtilp',       
        buttons:[ 
            {
                extend:    'excelHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> ',
                titleAttr: 'Exportar a Excel',
                className: 'btn btn-success',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
                }
            },
            {
                extend:    'pdfHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> ',
                titleAttr: 'Exportar a PDF',
                className: 'btn btn-danger',
                      exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 0,1,2,10,11,12,13,14,15]
                }
            },
            {
                extend:    'print',
                text:      '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> ',
                titleAttr: 'Imprimir',
                className: 'btn btn-info',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 0,1,2,10,11,12,13,14,15]
                }
            },
        ]           
    });
```

"Como puedes apreciar , si tienes botones para exportación como yo , lo unico que tienes que hacer es agregar exportOptions , y en el apartado columns , pones las posiciones de las columnas que deseas que se visualizen,eso es todo! "

Comment: Por favor agregar el codigo de tu datatable para poder ayudar de una manera mas efectiva

Comment: @David081 Hay añadi el código! :)

Comment: @LuisCifuentes las respuestas van en el área de respuestas. Elimina la parte que sirve de respuesta y agregala como respuesta. El sitio funciona así: una pregunta específica y bien formulada y una o varias respuestas en el área de respuestas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola para ocultar columnas de un datatable que no quieras que se muestren debes pasarle la propiedad visible false.

Por ejemplo yo tengo el siguiente datatable

```
 let table = $(grilla).addClass("nowrap").addClass("tblBandeja").addClass("dataTable").DataTable({
    data: datos,
    order: [],
    className: 'hhcc',
    columns: [
        /*0*/{ title: "IDIC", className: "text-center dt-control" },
        /*1*/{ title: "Fecha de ingreso", className: "text-center dt-control" },
        /*2*/{ title: "Paciente", className: "text-center overflow-auto dt-control" },
        /*3*/{ title: "Estado", className: "text-center dt-control" },
        /*4*/{ title: "Solicitud origen", className: "text-center overflow-auto dt-control" },
        /*5*/{ title: "Prof Solicita", className: "text-center dt-control" },
        /*6*/{ title: "Solicitud destino", className: "text-center overflow-auto dt-control" },
        /*7*/{ title: "Prof. destino", className: "text-center" },
        /*8*/{ title: "Diagnóstico", className: "text-center overflow-auto" },
        /*9*/{ title: "Síntomas", className: "text-center overflow-auto" },
        /*10*/{ title: "Solicitud", className: "text-center" },
        /*11*/{ title: "Espera", className: "text-center" },
        /*12*/{ title: "Ambito", className: "text-center" },
        /*13*/{ title: "Patologia GES", className: "text-center" },
        /*14*/{ title: "TipoEstado", className: "text-center" },
        /*15*/{ title: "idPaciente", className: "text-center" },
        ///**/{ title: "idEspecialidad", className: "text-center" },
        /*16*/{ title: "Respuesta", className: "text-center" },
        //{ title: "Tiempo transcurrido", className: "text-center" },
        /*17*/{ title: "", className: "text-center  dt-control" },
        /*18*/{ title: "", className: "text-center" }
    ],"columnDefs":[
        {
            "targets": [3,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16],
            "visible": false
         }
    ]
```

Te explico como funciona.. al `datatable` le pase varias columnas (18 en total), pero abajo en "columnDefs", le especifico que quiero que algunas no se vean(estan ahi, pero ocultas)

La numeracion de las columnas empieza en 0 (0 seria la primera columna),1,2,3 de izquierda a derecha.
En este ejemplo se ocultan las columnas
"targets": `[3= estado,     7=profDestino,8=diagnistico,9=sintomas,10=solicitud,12=ambito,13=patologia GES,14=tipoEstados,15=idPaciente,16=Respuesta]`
Te dejo la documentacion del datatable a continuacion: [Datatable columns](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs)

Comment: Esta es la respuesta correcta. Y además un link a la documentación. Yay!

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo!

Comment: Esta bastante completa, aunque me produjo un error , aún puedo observarlo, añadire el codigo de datatables en "editado", de antemano Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Ya encontre una solución en casos si tienes botones de exportacion , lo dejare en el editado 2 por si alguien le sirve!